# Is there a way to find all examples of a specific Assembly instruction in gdb?

Tags: assembly, gdb

For example, I want to find every jmp instance in memory. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: How about using objdump to dump the contents of the executable?  Then grep could find them for you.

Comment: No, there isn't, because there's no general way to find the start of an x86 instruction.  Any obfuscation technique can make it hard for a disassembler to stay in sync with execution.  I assume you're talking about x86; if not then tag appropriately.  A fixed-width instruction set like AArch64 would be much easier, and I'm sure there are some fixed-width ISAs where jump instructions use the `jmp` mnemonic.

Comment: The devil is in the details, so to understand what it is you want to accomplish and why, go a long way to eliciting good answers. I not suggesting your need is not legitimate, but many of us in the community lean toward the suspicious side when someone wants to hack, but really evasive about any details.

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you tell us *why* you specifically look for `JMP` instructions. If it is transfer of control you look for, the program could just as well use `CALL`, or -  if trying to trick you - hide a `JMP x` as `PUSH x` + `RET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find *possible* X86 `jmp` instances by scanning executable memory pages of the target process for initial bytes that might begin a `jmp` ([see here, for example](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html)) and then doing some reality check — e.g. whether the address the suspected command points to actually exists, etc.

However, even this approach cannot guarantee that you catch them all™: if the author was mean enough, the program in question can e.g. generate code on the stack, execute it and wipe it immediately after return.

So yeah, @PeterCordes is right: there is no general way of doing that. However, if you are sure that no anti-debug tricks are expected (and you have [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) installed on your machine), then you can simply run:

```
objdump -D /insert/executable/file/name.here -j .text -j .plt | grep -P $'^ *[0-9a-f]+:\t+([0-9a-f]{2} )+ +\t+jmp'
```

this command operates on files rather than on memory, but still it *might* give you what you want.